# Automatic update of numeric increment

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, excel-2013, automatic-updates

I use Excel 2013 but I do not know how to have a column with incremental numbers update automatically whenever I delete or add a row.

How can I achieve that?

Example

```
01
02
03
04
```

If I delete row `02`, I would like that the program automatically sets the following row as `02` instead of `03`, etc and if I add a row between `03` and `04`, then that added row should show `04` automatically and `04` become `05` and so on.

Comment: You want this value in the 1st column ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `=Row()` or that plus an offset, if required.

Comment: please be more explicit I don't understand your answer

Comment: This is the answer (as I understand the question)

Answer (score 0):

You may write value as `=`, then address of upper cell (press `up`) and then `+1`.
E.g. for cell `B2` it would be `=B1+1`.
Then hold mouse button on the bottom-right angle of that cell and drag mouse bottom as far as you need.

Comment: but when I add a row, that cell is without =B44+1

Comment: and also the formula is broken. in short it does not update automatically my whole column

Comment: If you use an Excel Table (Insert Ribbon > Table) then formulas will carry over into new rows automatically.